# how to implement this hierarchical UI found in iPad in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Check the screenshot below from Omnigroup, note the nested cards, how do you think we can implement a similar one in Delphi? Custom draw Virtual treeview? Any other hints? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An owner draw treeview might do the job. You could look at Virtual Treeview which is an open source component (and according to another SO question on of the best).

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that nested panels with captions would do the job nicely. If you want something more or less ready made, [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com)'s TAdvToolPanel comes to mind. Haven't used them for this kind of thing, but they are nestable, so you should be able to get something working fairly quickly.